# How to read data from google sheet through google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-sheets

I have a local flask app that is reading data from a csv file. Using the below code, I am able to successfully read in the data from columns one and two of a spreadsheet called "Vocab". the "service_account.json" is currently saved in my local working directory with my other application files.

```
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='service_account.json')
    sh = gc.open("Vocab")
    worksheetOne = sh.sheet1
    self.columnOne = [str(i) for i in worksheetOne.col_values(1)]
    self.columnTwo = [str(i) for i in worksheetOne.col_values(2)]
```

I am now trying to deploy this flask app to google app engine, but I am not sure on how to replace the local "service_account.json" file that I am using for credentials so that I am able to access my google sheet info. What would be the best way to access my google sheet info from my google app?

Comment: Can you deploy `service_account.json` with your app and do it the same way?

Comment: yep I can! easy fix

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to replace it? You can include it in the deploy so it is read the same way